# How to write AdminCleint Mock test

Tags: junit, apache-kafka

I am using kafka and Spring and stuck to write one Junit Test case.

Following is piece of code that I want to test.
you it can be seen KafkaAdminClient.create( is static method and I am unable to mock this.

Could some suggest me how I can achieve mocking for this.

public

```
boolean isBrokerRunning() {
    boolean isKafkaRunning = true;
    try {
        ListTopicsResult topics = createAdminClient().listTopics();
        topics.names().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        isKafkaRunning = false;
    }
    return isKafkaRunning;
}

public AdminClient createAdminClient() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers);
    properties.put("connections.max.idle.ms", 10000);
    properties.put("request.timeout.ms", 3000);
    return KafkaAdminClient.create(properties);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this same issue. After spending around 2 hrs I managed to use MockAdminClient.
Just create a MockAdminClient with dummy nodes and controller.

```
Node controller = new Node(0, "localhost", 8121);
List<Node> brokers = Arrays.asList(
    controller,
    new Node(1, "localhost", 8122),
    new Node(2, "localhost", 8123));
AdminClient mockAdminClient = new MockAdminClient(brokers, controller);

final NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic("some_topic", 1, (short) 1);
mockAdminClient.createTopics(ImmutableList.of(newTopic));

assertTrue(testClass.topicExists("test_topic", mockAdminClient));
```

Answer (score -1):

In case the AdminClient have to be initiated in the constructor, where AdminClient static methods have to be mocked. I did this using MockedStatic from Mockito-Inline and MockAdminClient

```
@BeforeEach
void setUp() {

    // Creat mock Admin Client
    final Node controller = new Node(0, "localhost", 8121);
    final List<Node> brokers = Arrays.asList(
            controller,
            new Node(1, "localhost", 8122),
            new Node(2, "localhost", 8123));
    mockAdminClient = new MockAdminClient(brokers, controller);

    try (MockedStatic<AdminClient> adminClientMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(AdminClient.class)) {
        adminClientMockedStatic.when(() -> AdminClient.create(anyMap())).thenReturn(mockAdminClient);
        KafkaProperties kafkaProperties = new KafkaProperties();
        kafkaProperties.setBootstrapServers(Arrays.asList("dummyBootstrapServer:0001"));
        kafkaFacade = new KafkaFacade(kafkaProperties);
    }

    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(kafkaFacade, "numberOfPartition", NO_OF_PARTITIONS);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(kafkaFacade, "retentionValue", 86400000);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(kafkaFacade, "replicationFactor", NO_OF_REPLICAS);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(kafkaFacade, "priority", PRIORITY);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(kafkaFacade, "prefix", TOPIC_PREFIX);
}
```